# How to properly configure nginx for an api calls?

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx, docker-compose, axios

I'm trying to build an application using nginx and php fpm.

My server configuration

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  127.0.0.1;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }


    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location /api/ {
        root /var/www/html/public;
        fastcgi_pass   fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/html/public/index.php;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

My docker-compose

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  frontend:
  backend:
  database:
  nginx.conf:

services:
  frontend:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 8087:80
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/dist:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./backend/:/var/www/html
      - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    links:
      - fpm
    container_name: nginx
  fpm:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./backend/backend.dockerfile
    container_name: fpm
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    volumes:
      - ./backend/:/var/www/html
      - ./www.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
    links:
      - database
    env_file: ./backend/.env
  database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: database
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'database'
      MYSQL_USER: 'user'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
```

Here is my nginx configuration

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }


    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location /api/ {
        root /var/www/html/public;
        fastcgi_pass   fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/html/public/index.php;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I am using axios for sending the request and laravel as api.

This is the way I am trying to send a request.

```
async postProject(data) {
        const response = await axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1/api/project`, data, {
            headers: headers
        });
    }
```

This is a route, that supposed to trigger controller on backend

```
Route::post('/api/project', [ProjectController::class, 'postProject']);
```

But when I'm trying to send a request, I keep getting 404 error from server. I've tried to send a request from postman, but still get a 404. I suspect that problem is my server configuration, but wasn't able to find it myself.

Here is some logs from nginx docker container regarding this request

`172.23.0.1 - - [21/Dec/2023:08:20:41 +0000] "POST /api/project HTTP/1.1" 404 32 "http://127.0.0.1:8087/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"`

Could you guide me where to search for mistakes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`location /api/` in your Nginx config causes Nginx to strip `/api` from the request URL before passing it on, so if you POST to `/api/project` your app receives a POST for `/project`.

To fix it, remove the last slash in your location in the Nginx config, so it becomes `location /api`. Then it won't strip `/api` before passing it on.